# What compound is this?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What compound is this please? A painkiller?

[image]

Comment: Please try to include full details when asking a question, otherwise it may sound you just want to get done with your homework. Include details that will be beneficial to other users as well.

Answer (score 7):

It is [diclofenac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diclofenac), which is described there as "applied to reduce inflammation and as an analgesic reducing pain in certain conditions".

By drawing the structure in [emolecules](https://orderbb.emolecules.com/search/#?smiles=OC(%3DO)Cc1ccccc1Nc1c(Cl)cccc1Cl&searchtype=ex&similimit=0.8&system-type=BB&p=1) (search mask [here](https://www.emolecules.com/)), I selected the entry as the free acid (and not the sodium salt, for example). A click on "LSKB" below the structure representation linked to the next database in which the restraint "where to find" was lessened to "chemicals in literature". Eventually I was guided towards this page, which a first entry name not following systematic nomenclature; an often seen pattern for pharmaceutical products:

[image]

To round the picture, if looking for physical chemical data, I would repeat the query, then *including* its salts (like the sodium salt).

Comment: This is also a good structure search engine that works in android and iphones as well:http://www.organic-chemistry.org/chemicals/structuresearch.htm